# I couldn't create a method to count the number of occurrences

Tags: java, arrays

I've created a method to count the number of occurrences in an array, but I can't compile and run it.

Compiler gives the error:

> The method occurence(int[]) in the type countOfOccurence is not applicable for the arguments (int)

```
public class countOfOccurence {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] number = {15,16,14};

        System.out.print(occurence(number[15]));
    }

    public static int occurence(int[] number) {

        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < number.length; i++) {

            for(int k = 0 ; i < number.length; i++) {
                if(number[k] == number[i]) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the `System.out.print(occurence(number[15]));` call you're passing to your method a 15th element of the `number` array which would be an int. Even if that would compile you would get  `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because that array only got 3 elements. You probably wanted to call `System.out.print(occurence(number));` instead.

Comment: You `occurance` method counts twice the number of times a number appears plus one, and sums this count for all numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Your `occurrence` method is expecting an array, but you are just passing an int to it (the 15th element from your array, which will also cause a runtime error as there are only 3 elements in your array).

But I also think your logic is off here, your current method (given that it would compile) will count all occurrences of all duplicate numbers in your array, not just the number you would want.

First off all, your occurrence method would need 2 arguments, the actual array and the number you want to count the occurrences of. You don't need an inner loop, just keep your outer loop and check inside whether the array element equals your desired number.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] number = {15,16,14};
  System.out.print(occurence(number, 15));
}

public static int occurence(int[] numberArray, int number) {
  int count = 0;
  for(int i = 0 ; i < numberArray.length; i++) {
    if(numberArray[i] == number) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

Of course there are better / cleaner ways to count occurrences of elements in an array, for example using the `Streams` api, if you would want to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

`occurence(int[] number)` function accepts the integer array parameter. And, you are calling the function with `occurence(number[15])`. By `number[15]`, it means 15th-index position from number array, which is also not valid in your code.

For your scenario to work, occurence function should be changed to accept two parameters like `public static int occurence(int[] numbers, int number)`. And, call it by `occurence(number, 15)`.